# image extension is not showing in PHP file-upload

Tags: php, image, file, upload

I'm using this piece of code to handle an input for uploading multiple images, and resizing them as well. It works but there is one small thing that doesn't want to do its job. The **extension** that I'm trying to get is not showing up in the file's name.

Here is the piece of code where the problem should be:

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if(is_array($_FILES)) { 
        foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] as $uploadedFile) { 
        //$uploadedFile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
            if($uploadedFile <> ''){
                $sourceProperties = getimagesize($uploadedFile);
                $newFileName = time();
                $dirPath = "../images/";
                $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];

                switch ($imageType) {

                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $imageSrc = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedFile); 
                        $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                        imagepng($tmp,$dirPath. $newFileName. "_thump.". $ext);
                        break;           

                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $imageSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedFile); 
                        $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                        imagejpeg($tmp,$dirPath. $newFileName. "_thump.". $ext);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $imageSrc = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedFile); 
                        $tmp = imageResize($imageSrc,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                        imagegif($tmp,$dirPath. $newFileName. "_thump.". $ext);
                        break;

                    default:
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>File is not an image.</div>";
                        exit;
                        break;
                }

            }
         }
     }
}
```

For an example, something it is now saving is called **1547265041_thump.** in my database.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check `$ext` getting extension or not.
If it not getting check `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` reading or not.
You can debug by `echo` them.

Check you database character length.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked them, and $ext is empty. I should have said that in the question already.

Comment: Did you check `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` are getting correctly?

Comment: I tried 'print_r' because it seems to be an array. The output when uploading a picture was Array ( [0] => example.jpeg ) @damnguy

Comment: Now that I know that this is an array, I think it's logical that it doesn't work. I made a counter to find out the array ext and this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` seems to be an array, which is logical since you can upload multiple images at once. To loop through, I added a counter to the foreach to output the extension. Now it works well!